# Facebook share link: specify image and custom message shown in post

Tags: facebook, web-applications, social-sharing-buttons

In my web application, I am allowing users to share their affiliate link to Facebook. I am currently doing this using this URL:

```
<a target="_blank" onclick="return !window.open(this.href, 'Facebook', 'width=640,height=500')" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[App_Link]">
```

This results in a pop-up like this:

[image]

I want to be able to enhance this in two ways:

1. Specify the image that is shown along with this custom post (the company logo)
2. Specify a custom sentence or two in the *Say something about this...* text box

Are one or both of these possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook uses [**OpenGraph**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph) to determine what the page is about if those details are blank it will harvest other elements of the page. So if you want custom descriptions and images used then ensure that whatever page is being linked has the following code in the `<head></head>`.

*For example:*

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Page Title Here" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Page Description" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Example" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/image-here.jpg" />
```

Comment: Any ideas about how I can put in custom text in the `Say something about this...` box?

Comment: @karancan Pre-filling the user message box is a violation of [Facebook Platform Policy, 2.3](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill) so I wouldn't imagine that Facebook provides a way to do that. A related topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5023658/404623